# Waiting for all threads to finish in Spring Integration

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-integration

I have a self-executable jar program that relies heavily on Spring Integration. The problem I am having is that the **program is terminating before the other Spring beans have completely finished**.

Below is a cut-down version of the code I'm using, I can supply more code/configuration if needed. The entry point is a main() method, which bootstraps Spring and starts the import process:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("flow.xml");
    DataImporter importer = (DataImporter)ctx.getBean("MyImporterBean");
    try {
        importer.startImport();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

The DataImporter contains a simple loop that fires messages to a Spring Integration gateway. This delivers an active "push" approach to the flow, rather than the common approach of polling for data. This is where my problem comes in:

```
public void startImport() throws Exception {
    for (Item item : items) {
        gatewayBean.publish(item);
        Thread.sleep(200); // Yield period
    }
}
```

For completeness, the flow XML looks something like this:

```
<gateway default-request-channel="inChannel" service-interface="GatewayBean" />

<splitter input-channel="inChannel" output-channel="splitChannel" />

<payload-type-router input-channel="splitChannel">
    <mapping type="Item" channel="itemChannel" />
    <mapping type="SomeOtherItem" channel="anotherChannel" />
</payload-type-router>

<outbound-channel-adapter channel="itemChannel" ref="DAOBean" method="persist" />
```

The flow starts and processes items effectively, but once the startImport() loop finishes the main thread terminates and tears down all the Spring Integration threads immediately. This results in a race condition, the last (n) items are not completely processed when the program terminates.

I have an idea of maintaining a reference count of the items I am processing, but this is proving to be quite complicated, since the flow often splits/routes the messages to multiple service activators - meaning it is difficult to determine if each item has "finished".

What I think I need is some way to either check that no Spring beans are still executing, or to flag that all items sent to the gateway have been completely processed before terminating.

**My question is, how might I go about doing either of these, or is there a better approach to my problem I haven't thought of?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not using a request-response pattern here.

outbound-channel-adapter is a fire and forget action, if you want to wait for the response you should use an outbound-gateway that will wait for response, and connect the response to the original gateway, then in java sendAndReceive not just publish.

Comment: This was indeed my problem. I modified my flow to use <service-activator> instead of <outbound-channel-adapter>, and connected the result to an asynchronous gateway. I can now wait for completion using a Future.isDone(). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you can get an `Item` to determine, whether it is still needed or not (processingFinished() or something similar executed in the back-end-stages), you can register all `Item`s at a central authority, which keeps track of the number of non-finished `Item`s and effecitvely determines a termination-condition.

If this approach is feasible, you could even think of packaging the items into `FutureTask`-objects or make use of similar concepts from `java.util.concurrent`.

Edit: Second Idea:

Have you thought about making the channels more intelligent? A sender closes the channel once it does not send any more data. In this scenario, the worker-beans do not have to be deamon threads but can determine their termination-criterion based on a closed and empty input channel.

Comment: Some good ideas in there. However, in my project the "Item" class is too generic (part of a model layer) to add import logic. I might look into ways to do something similar with the message headers. FutureTask et al would be nice but I'm struggling to see a way to utilise the concurrent framework for my specific problem...